# Asynchronous SQLDataTable from ExecuteReaderAsync - makes sense?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asynchronous, ado.net

I am using ASP.NET 4.5, with `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` set.

I have an old data helper library method that returns a SQLDatatable using `SQLDataAdapter.Fill()`.

I want to add a method to return `Task(of SQLDatatable)` - an async equivalent of the old method.

The code I have is like below (only the portion of code that matters is included):

Note:

- `GetConnectionString()` returns the sql connection string
- `GetSqlCmd(...)` returns a SQLCommand object
- `LogError()` logs any exception

  ```
  Using conn As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionString())
      Try
          cmd = GetSqlCmd(strSQL, conn, hash)
          Await conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)

          Using datareader = Await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(False)
              userDataTable.Load(datareader)
          End Using

      Catch ex As Exception
          LogError(ex)
      End Try

  End Using
  ```

And the code works in the ASP.NET application, once I add await to the library method call.

The thing I'm not really sure is **if the code above makes sense**. Certainly the SQLDataReader is async, but SQLDataTable.Load(datareader) doesn't appear to use ReadAsync (as far as I can tell)...

Does this fact make the above code pointless - meaning, **"ExecuteReaderAsync without ReadAsync" is pointless?**

Answer (score 0):

It is not pointless. Using async is not all or nothing. In a web app async IO is about block threads less. It is not required to not block them at all.

You have eliminated the blocking resulting from `OpenAsync` and `ExecuteReaderAsync`. Draining the reader is still synchronous.

That said, most web apps don't get any benefit at all from using async. For example it does not magically make your queries faster or add more capacity to the database server. So chose wisely.

Comment: the application this async method will be used on serves some sites that have close to 1000 concurrent users. I think in this case it makes sense to reduce blocking due to I/O, as much as possible, according to your answer. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: 1000 concurrent users != 1000 concurrent requests. Your app would crumble under 1000 concurrent requests. You cannot add more capacity by going async. Certainly not to the database. SQL Server executes queries synchronously for example. No problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

It is not "pointless", rather it helps that specific piece of code scale better. You don't *have to* use it everywhere but if you need to improve scalability, you should as much as possible.

Async is not about making anything faster, it is about making an app scalable. It is misleading at best (and totally wrong at worst) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25012216/251267) to say "...most web apps don't get any benefit at all from using async. For example it does not magically make your queries faster or add more capacity to the database server".

The apps that will get the most from going `async` are those that require scalability. Here is another answer on SO that has more detail - [Not much difference between ASP.NET Core sync and async controller actions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57892646/251267)

Not using `async` means your calls are blocking waiting for the db to do something. Using `async` means those threads that would've been blocking can actually do something else. This increases scalability. Microsoft's own Bing.com is internally run on SqlServer so SqlServer has no problem with scalability when designed and implemented correctly.